# store function results in a vector

Tags: r, function, vector, sampling, storing-data

I have a function here that takes samples, it works however I'm struggling to store the samples taken in a vector so that I may plot them; here is my function below:

```
InvCDF = function(n, sd) {
for (i in 1:n) {
u=runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
x = sqrt(-2*(sd^2)*log(1-u))
print(x)
}
}
```

I have tried creating a vector of 0's initially with

```
x = vector(mode="numeric",length=n)
```

then somehow fill in these 0's with the samples taken but it isn't working.

If someone could please assist with with storing my print(x) values in a vector I would be so happy

Comment: Which language is this in?

Comment: This is using R

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list for storing all the iteration of x.  then you need to call the required function to get those values i.e. here xx will store the results. As suggested by Roland, growing a list in the R is a very slow operation. You should use the vectorized approach when ever possible.

```
InvCDF = function(n, sd) {
    x=list()
    for (i in 1:n) {
        u=runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
        x[[i]] = sqrt(-2*(sd^2)*log(1-u))           
    }
    unlist(x)
}
xx=InvCDF(100,19)
```

You could pre-define a vector and use it in a loop. This which would be much faster than list operations.

```
x <- numeric(n)
InvCDF = function(n, sd) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        u=runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
        x[i] = sqrt(-2*(sd^2)*log(1-u))
    }
    x
}
```

Comment: No, there really is no need to use a list. And you really should not grow an object in a loop. That's one of the slowest operations possible. Just do `x <- numeric(n)` if you absolutely want to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah there is no need for list here. I didn't think enough about the problem  and merely just corrected OP's code. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no need to use a loop here. `runif` is vectorized as are `sqrt`, `log` etc.

```
InvCDF = function(n, sd) {
  u <- runif(n, 0, 1)
  sqrt(-2*(sd^2)*log(1-u))
}

set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
InvCDF(5, 1)
#[1] 0.7855916 0.9647926 1.3043220 2.1855104 0.6711903
```